# Front end entry form not saving on Craft CMS 4 multisite

Tags: multi-site, frontend, frontend-form, craft4, entry-form

I have created a basic entry form that simply saves a title but I can't seem to get it working.

I copied the code from Craft's documentation but that didn't work so I tried copying the code from another craft 4 site I built recently. The only difference I can see between the site that works and the one that doesn't is that one is a single site and the other is a multi site.

When I copied the code I made sure to change the sectionId. I've specified the siteId in a html tag because it threw an error when I tried:

```
 {{ hiddenInput('siteId', '{{ currentSite.id }}') }}
```

Here's my code:

```
{% extends "_layout.twig" %}

{% block content %}


{# Require that a user is logged in to view this form. #}
{% requireLogin %}


{% macro errorList(errors) %}
  {% if errors %}
  {{ ul(errors, {class: 'errors'}) }}
 {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{# If there were any validation errors, an `entry` variable will be 
 passed to the template, which contains the posted values 
 and validation errors. If that’s not set, we’ll default 
 to a new entry. #}
 {% set entry = entry ?? create('craft\\elements\\Entry') %}

 {# Add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to `<form>` if you’re 
  uploading files. #}
  <form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {{ csrfInput() }}
  {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
  {{ redirectInput('artists/{slug}') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '22') }}
  {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}

   <input type="hidden" name="siteId" value="{{ currentSite.id }}">


   <label for="title">Title</label>
   {{ input('text', 'title', entry.title, {
     id: 'title',
    }) }}
    {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}



    <div class="mb-6">
    <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 
     focus:outline-none focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm w-full sm:w- 
     auto px-5 py-2.5 text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 
     dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Publish</button>
    </div>
    </form>


    {% endblock %}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you double-checked that the current user has the necessary permissions to publish entries in the relevant section _and_ site(s)?

Comment: If permissions aren't the issue, please elaborate on exactly _how_ the form doesn't work, i.e. does submitting it yield any error messages, or does it simply refresh the page? Or does something else happen? A thing to try is adding a `{{ dump(entry.getErrors()|default }}` to the top of the page (to rule out any additional validation errors beyond the `title`).

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `siteId` input field to the form as follows should work:

```
{{ hiddenInput('siteId', currentSite.id) }}
```

Otherwise, please provide an error message so we can help you figure this out.